# Fade in & Scale effect in ReactJS modal window

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a modal window which I wrote in ReactJS.I need to realize Fade in Scale effect to this modal window.Something like  [**this**](https://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/) (Please look to effect with name **Fade in & Scale**).

I found  a library which realize that effect [**rodal**](http://chenjiahan.github.io/rodal/) (Please look to effect with name **Zoom**) but not in React way ,dynamically removing element from DOM.

So I wrote it from scratch.But I have a problem.When modal fade out scale animation work's but when it fade in it not work's.

Please help.

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-modal-9vee5)

My styled component style.

```
&.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    /* transition: opacity linear 0.15s; */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  &.fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
```

Comment: increase time of fade-in transaction as `transition: all 1.3s;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add scale to modal in order to achieve this
[Check the sandbok link](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-modal-wtxhc)

you need to add a `transform: scale(0);` to the main `div`, this will solve your issues.